# Slider on mainpage doesn't do what it needs to

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I stumbled across a problem with my slider, I want my slider to appear on the right side of my website when I'm hovering over there, and disappear when I'm hovering over to, for example, the left side.

Right now the slider is functional, but it only disappears when hovering over to, for example, my browser tabs or taskbar on windows.

Anyone a clue how to implement this?

```js
const sliderOverlay = document.querySelector('.slider-overlay');
const leftSide = document.getElementById('leftSide');
const mainPage = document.getElementById('mainPage');

mainPage.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  const mouseX = e.pageX;
  const leftSideBoundary = leftSide.getBoundingClientRect().right;

  if (mouseX >= leftSideBoundary) {
    // If mouse is on the right side of the leftSide element
    sliderOverlay.style.width = '20%'; // Or your desired width
    sliderOverlay.style.opacity = '1';
  } else {
    // If mouse is not over the leftSide element
    sliderOverlay.style.width = '0';
    sliderOverlay.style.opacity = '0';
  }
});
```

```css
.slider-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* Adjust darkness here */
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: width 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
}

#mainPage:hover .slider-overlay {
  width: 20%;
  /* Slide in from right to left */
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="page hidden" id="mainPage">
  <!-- Main content -->
  <div class="main-content">
    <!-- Your main content goes here -->
    <h1>Welcome to the Main Page</h1>
    <p>This is the content of the main page.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- Slider overlay -->

  <div class="slider-overlay" id="sliderOverlay">
    <h2>Slider Content</h2>
  </div>

</div>
```

I tried it together with ChatGPT but all the answers made it so that either the slider completely disappeared, nothing changed or it did appear but for a flash.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, you actually have some kind of conflicts here.
You are checking at some point the mouse position to change CSS attribute value and also using CSS :hover to change CSS attribute as well.
Also I notice an issue on the javascript code :

```
const leftSide = document.getElementById('leftSide');
```

There is no "leftSide" element on html then the Javascript code execution is failing.

Then, I propose kind of simplification :

- we are checking the position the position of the mouse to check if we are on right side or left side of the website
- we are removing the `:hover` behavior
- we are using position `right` CSS attribute instead of `width` (the problem with `width` is that as your overlay container will have a changing width, element inside the overlay will glitch when appearing)

```js
  const sliderOverlay = document.querySelector('.slider-overlay');
const overlayWidth = sliderOverlay.getBoundingClientRect().width;

sliderOverlay.style.right = '-' + overlayWidth + 'px';

document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    const mouseX = e.pageX;
    //const overlayWidth = sliderOverlay.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

    if (mouseX >= windowWidth - overlayWidth) {
        console.log('I am on right side of the website'); sliderOverlay.style.right = '0px'; // Or your desired width
        sliderOverlay.style.opacity = '1';
    } else {
        console.log('I am on left side of the website');
        sliderOverlay.style.right = '-' + overlayWidth + 'px';
        sliderOverlay.style.opacity = '0';
    }
});
```

```css
   .slider-overlay {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -500px;
        width: 500px;
        height: 100%;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        /* Adjust darkness here */
        z-index: 1;
        opacity: 0.5;
        transition: right 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="page hidden" id="mainPage">
    <!-- Main content -->
    <div class="main-content">
        <!-- Your main content goes here -->
        <h1>Welcome to the Main Page</h1>
        <p>This is the content of the main page.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Slider overlay -->

    <div class="slider-overlay" id="sliderOverlay">
        <h2>Slider Content</h2>
    </div>

</div>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: it first didnt work but i forgot the document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { hahaha! It finally works, Thank you so much!!